# how to upgrade ti.cloudpush in titanium studio

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

I am using, 3.1.3 GA, I want to upgrade ti.cloudpush from 2.3.2 to 2.3.3, how to do this. any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can install the cloudpush module as follows

1. You need to go [here](https://github.com/hieupham007/Titanium_Mobile/blob/b33102312f137fb8ee6c1aa02374aba9c0968f68/support/module/packaged/ti.cloudpush-android-2.3.3.zip). Download the zip file and save it in your machine.
2. Open the Titanium Studio
3. Select Help-> Install Mobile Module
4. Click *Browse...* button on the *Install from URL:* input and select the downloaded zip file

*Output can be set to default Titanium SDK if you are unsure of where to install module*

5. Click the OK button, module will be installed

Once the module is installed, you will get a notification at bottom left of Ti Studio.

6. Now open TiApp.xml of your project
7. Double click on cloudPush module in the modules box and select the version of cloudpush module.

You will get more information from [Installing Titanium Modules](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Using_a_Module-section-30082372_UsingaModule-Installingmodules)

Hope it helped you :)